# How to get replaceDataSource to work with personal geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, personal-geodatabase, pyscripter

I am having trouble using the arcpy.mapping's replaceDataSource with a personal geodatabase. The script runs, but does nothing if I run the script in the python window of ArcMap. If I run it in PyScripter, PyScripter stops working and gives the message: *EOFError: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host*.

It ought to be a simple fix; the feature classes are the exact same, just from a personal geodatabase that has been copied to a different location.

```
import arcpy

fcSource = r'c:\users\athom\Documents\GIS\GIS_computer_06_20_2013\GIS_LOCAL_MASTER\DATA\Vector_Data\Toponomy\TH_toponomy_250k.mdb'
fcName = 'sl_anno250k'
mapDoc = r'c:\users\athom\Documents\GIS\GIS_computer_06_20_2013\GIS_LOCAL_MASTER\MAPS\Map_Projects\TEST\AAAJ2011-004-02 TH Traditional Territory.mxd'
MxD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument (mapDoc)
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(MxD):
    if lyr.supports ("DATASOURCE"):
        if lyr.dataSource == r"N:\DATA\Vector_Data\Toponomy\TH_toponomy_250k.mdb\sl_anno250k":
            lyr.replaceDataSource(fcSource, 'ACCESS_WORKSPACE', fcName)
            arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your script in the Python window of ArcMap with the AAAJ2011-004-02 TH Traditional Territory.mxd open, you should reference your map document as `MxD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument ('current')`.
If you run it with another mxd open, you should keep your mapDoc variable as it is but add `mapDoc.save()` in the end of your script.

Comment: The solution work great if run within the map, but PyScripter still crashes if it is run as a standalone script. Any clue as to the reason?

Comment: Is your version of PyScripter compatible with your version of Python? Besides this I don't know what could cause the crash.

Comment: PyScripter works great, except when it runs into a personal geodatabase when trying to run lyr.replaceDataSource in a standalone script.

Comment: The Fault Module is 'LayerLib.dll and the Exception Code is reported as 'c0000005'. It appears to be similar to http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/81528-Python-crashes-running-stand-alone-script-composite-locator-AGS-10.1-SP1-desktop